# VScode: how-to change the color of HTML open and closing tag

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, jsx, syntax-highlighting

How can I change the color of the HTML open/close tags in VScode to match the image below? I have tried using the `Highlight Matching Tag` extension and the following settings, but this only works on selecting (onFocus) of the tags. I want the actual font color for open tags to be different than all the closing tags. Thank you!

```
  "highlight-matching-tag.styles": {
    "opening": {
      "name": {
        "custom": {
          "color": "#007fff",
        }
      }
    },
    "closing": {
      "name": {
        "custom": {
          "color": "#F02931"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

[image: desired-output]

Comment: In a react  jsx file?

Comment: yes, or just HTML

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by customizing the VS Code theme that you are currently using (see the end result on the last image).

**CUTOMIZING THE THEME**

In the VSCode open the Command Palette by pressing `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P`, and type/select `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`.
This will open the editor Settings `.json` file.
Set/add new rules for the editor token color customization.

Adding the below snippet to the `settings.json` will change the color of the closing tags (name) in JSX, for the theme *Dark (Visual Studio)*.

> **TL;DR**
>
> Paste the below snippet to your editor settings JSON, to enable the color > rules for a particular theme.

`settings.json`

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "[Visual Studio Dark]": { // Name of the theme that we want to customize, same as the value from "workbench.colorTheme"
  "textMateRules": [ // TextMate grammars tokenization settings
    {
      "name": "Opening JSX tags",
      "scope": [
        "entity.name.tag.open.jsx", // HTML opening tags (in JSX)
        "support.class.component.open.jsx", // JSX Component opening tags
      ],
      "settings": {
        "foreground": "#007fff",
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Closing JSX tags",
      "scope": [
        "entity.name.tag.close.jsx", //  HTML closing tags (in JSX)
        "support.class.component.close.jsx", // JSX Component closing tags
      ],
      "settings": {
        "foreground": "#F02931",
      }
    },
  ]
 }
}
```

[image]

**SETTING ADDITIONAL SCOPES:**

Additionally you can inspect the particular token (e.g. tag) in order to see the name of the scope that you want to style.

In the the Command Palette `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P` open the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` to see the TextMate scope names of the parts (opening tag, closing tag, etc.) that you want to modify.

[image]

[image]

For a more advanced matching and going beyond jsx you may want to reference the [TextMate grammars](https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars)